# Sequence of functions converging in finite steps at every point

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to know if there is a name and/or specific results for pointwise converging sequences of real functions $$f_n\to f,$$ from a closed interval $I$ to itself, having the property that for every $x\in I$ , there is $\bar{n}$ such that $$f_n(x)=f(x)\ \text{for every}\  n>\bar{n}$$ Notice that $\bar{n}(x)$ can be unbounded.
A more specific question: which functions $f$ can be obtained by means of such a kind of convergence if every function $f_n$ is required to be continuous?

Clearly they have to be in Baire class 1 and clearly they are not necessarily continuous.

Comment: What does "in finite time" in the title mean? I'm not sure what time has to do with the question?

Comment: The precise meaning is given in the text. I used "time" in the title since I have some applications in mind, but they are not important for the question.

Comment: Well, please change the title to be more relevant to your question (I would get rid of the "in finite time" part). Also, you could make the title more specific to the question (maybe you can even fit your entire question in the title, which I would recommend, as it makes it easier for people to search for your question in future using the search bar). As for your question, the only thing I can think of that's interesting about such functions is that they are easy to describe/define, as you did in your question. Other than that, I don't think they are anything special...

Comment: „Pointwise eventually constant“ would be a somewhat straightforward name